# How to proceed for these two differential equations?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

1) Using $z=x+y$, solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x+y+2}{x+y+5}$$

My attempt,so $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{z+2}{z+5}$$

How to integrate then to become y?

2)Using $v=2x-y$, solve $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x-y-1}{2x-y+3}$$

so, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{v-1}{v+3}$$

How to proceed then?

Comment: I asked a question a while back on the general approach for these sorts of ODEs [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/941907/170231)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $$z=x+y\implies {dz\over dx}=1+{dy\over dx}$$ Then
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{z+2}{z+5}+1\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{2z+7}{z+5}$$ is a separable equation. $$\frac{z+5}{2z+7} dz=dx$$ integrate both sides of the latter.

Comment: Don't  understand how to remove y.

Comment: Please see the answer again.

Comment: I got $z-2\ln (z+7)+c_1-x=0$

Comment: That's ok but replace z with x+y... you are done. The second equation is similar.

Comment: There is a typo in my answer. I'll correct it.

Comment: $$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{z+2}{z+5}+1\implies \frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{2z+7}{z+5}$$

Comment: Did you update "the given answer"? Before I saw no logarithms there. As it is stated now, I don't see which one should be alright (sorry no time now to do the calculations)

Comment: I got the answer $2x+2y+3\ln (2x+2y+7)+7+c_1=4x$. But the answer given is $\frac{(x+y)^2}{2}+y+c_1=0$ Wonder why