# how to solve ODE $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x+y+2}$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I've been trying to self teach my self calculus and came across an ODE that I am unsure how to solve.
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x+y+2}$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. community. What did you try to do? These are typical questions where there is little to no effort. This community does not accept questions where there has been no minimal effort.

Comment: *Hint*: let $X=x+2$.

Comment: It might not have a solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x+y+2}{y}$ is a linear ODE.

Comment: See the general method [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/941907/170231)

Comment: @user170231 thank you!